# open.ppsx file in fully slideshow mode

Tags: c#

I want to open ppsx file fully in slideshow mode I'm using the code below

```
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application ppApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application();
            ppApp.Visible = MsoTriState.msoTrue;

            Presentations ppPresens = ppApp.Presentations;
            Presentation objPres = ppPresens.Open(powerPointFilePath, MsoTriState.msoFalse, MsoTriState.msoTrue, MsoTriState.msoTrue);
            Slides objSlides = objPres.Slides;

            SlideShowWindows objSSWs;
            SlideShowSettings objSSS;
            //Run the Slide show                                
            objSSS = objPres.SlideShowSettings;
            objSSS.Run();
            objSSWs = ppApp.SlideShowWindows;
            while (objSSWs.Count >= 1) System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
            //Close the presentation without saving changes and quit PowerPoint                             
            objPres.Close();
            ppApp.Quit();
```

but it shown like this:
[Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IprX4.png)

I don't want to open powerpoint editable file with slideshow
please help thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are opening it with the Office Interop. You want to have Windows handle wich Programm and with wich Arguments to open it with. At wich point it should pick the default (Open in Show Mode) for this file extension.

Those extra file extensions are there *specifically* to have a different default operation associated with them. There might be 0 bits of difference between a ppts or dotx file and it's baseline ???x counterpart.

Process.Run() can be used to do what is effectively the same as putting something into the Run Dialog or Commandline. Just point to the file and have windwos decide how to open it. It will do the same as if you Double Clicked hte file in the Explorer.